# Proving the Schwarz Inequality

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I'm working through Spivak's Calculus textbook on Chapter 1, 19d.

The question posed is as follows:

[image: FIRST IMAGE]

[image: SECOND IMAGE]

Now the part I'm lost on is 19d. I was able to find the **only when** cases for parts a and b, but now I'm lost for part c. How do I find the case that equality holds only when $x_1 = (lambda)(y_1)$ and $x_2 = (lambda)(y_2)$?

A hint is fine, I'm not just looking for an answer. I'm just really stuck on this one. I have a feeling it has something to do with the terms $(x_1y_1 + x_2y_2)^2$ or $(x_2y_1 - x_1y_2)^2$ but I'm not sure.

Thank you ahead of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the (c) part of 19(d), given that equality of Schwarz inequality holds, i.e.

$$\color{red}{(x_1y_1 + x_2y_2)^2} = \color{blue}{(x_1^2+x_2^2)(y_1^2+y_2^2)}$$

Using $\color{blue}{(x_1^2+x_2^2) (y_1^2+y_2^2)} = \color{red}{(x_1y_1 + x_2y_2)^2} + \color{green}{(x_1y_2 - x_2y_1)^2}$, the identity from part (c):

$$\begin{align*}
\color{green}{(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)^2} &= 0\\
x_1y_2 - x_2y_1 &= 0\\
x_1y_2 &= x_2y_1\\
\end{align*}$$

Either $y_1=y_2=0$, or WLOG assume $y_2 \ne 0$,

$$\begin{align*}
 x_1 &=\frac{x_2y_1}{y_2}\\
x_1 &= \frac{x_2}{y_2} \cdot y_1
\end{align*}$$

By taking $\lambda = \frac{x_2}{y_2}$, there is a number $\lambda$ that satisfies both $x_1 = \lambda y_1$ and $x_2 = \lambda y_2$.

Comment: But why does part c tell us that $(x_1y_2 - x_2y_1)^2 = 0$ for equality to hold? Because equality holds only when $(x_1^2 + x_2^2)(y_1^2 + y_2^2) ⩾ (x_1)(y_1) + (x_2)(y_2)$ ?

Comment: @kyle: square both sides of the Schwarz inequality (which we’re assuming is an *equality* here). This means the entire left-hand side equals the first term on the right-hand side. This, the second term must be equal to $0$.

Comment: @kylecampbell Equality holds implies (by squaring both sides of Schwarz inequality)

$$\color{red}{(x_1y_1 + x_2y_2)^2} = \color{blue}{(x_1^2+x_2^2)(y_1^2+y_2^2)}$$

Part (c) says

$$\color{blue}{(x_1^2+x_2^2) (y_1^2+y_2^2)} = \color{red}{(x_1y_1 + x_2y_2)^2} + \color{green}{(x_1y_2 - x_2y_1)^2}$$

Then $\color{green}{(x_1y_2 - x_2y_1)^2}$ can only be $0$.

Comment: @kylecampbell I assumed you directly used the identity in part (c) and the inequality 

$$(x_1y_2 - x_2y_1)^2 \ge 0 \tag 1$$

to prove Schwarz inequality. If equality holds for Schwarz inequality, then equality should also hold for inequality $(1)$.

Comment: I see now. Thanks a lot Clayton and @peterwhy